# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django, sphinx, django-sphinx

I read this article http://eshlox.net/en/2012/09/13/sphinxsearch-and-django-ubuntu/

In view i get error for code: total = query_results['total']

error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
def search(request):
    if request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        query = request.GET.get('q', '')
        s = SphinxClient()
        s.SetServer('localhost', 9312)
        s.SetLimits(0, 16777215)
        if s.Status():
            query_results = s.Query(query)
            total = query_results['total']
            pages_id = [page['id'] for page in query_results['matches']]
            if pages_id:
                results = Page.objects.filter(id__in=pages_id)
            else:
                results = None
            if results:
                paginator = Paginator(results, 25)
                page = request.GET.get('page')
                try:
                    results = paginator.page(page)
                except PageNotAnInteger:
                    results = paginator.page(1)
                except EmptyPage:
                    results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            return render(request, 'wiki/search.html',
                          {'results': results,'total': total,
                           'query': query, 'form': form})
        else:
            logger = logging.getLogger('helper')
            logger.error('Sphinxsearch Error! %s' % s.GetLastError())
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Search server is '
                                 'not responding. Administrator '
                                 'has been informed.')
            form = SearchForm()
            return render(request, 'wiki/search.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render(request, 'wiki/search.html', {'form': form})
```

> Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in
> ```
>
> get_response
>
> ```
>                         response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
>     ...
> ▶ Local vars
> /home/max/askmoiseev/ask/views.py in search
>
>               total = query_results['total']
>
>     ...
> ▶ Local vars
> ```

Please tell me what could be the error?

Comment: as the error says, `query_results` is None.

Comment: The question is that I do not understand why query_results is None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine your query results are None

```
query_results = s.Query(query)
```

so when you try to access

```
total = query_results['total']
```

you get the `__getitem__` error because None is not a List.

Here's an example from the interpreter.

```
>>> n = None
>>> n['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Try running the query in the shell - `django-admin.py shell` then

```
s = SphinxClient()
s.SetServer('localhost', 9312)
s.SetLimits(0, 16777215)
query_results = s.Query(query)
```

Good luck,
Sam

Comment: I do not understand why query_results is None, I followed the article, sphinxsearch works, problem in view((((

Comment: Try running it in the shell. I added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

You should check GetLastError and maybe GetLastWarning **before** you try using query_results, to make sure the query succeeded.

The bonus you get to find out WHY the query failed. It would perhaps be better if the api raised proper exceptions on failures, but well, it doesn't.

As another point, your setLimits is absurdly high, its quite possible its failing from trying to obtain too many results.

Really you should do paging directly in sphinx, only get the ids for the current page, rather than get all ids, and then page.